# How to put "create.html.erb" in a modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal

The modal is popping up for **`new.html.erb`**, but not **`create.html.erb`**. Why?

A user clicks "+ Challenge" on **`header.html.erb`**:

### header.html.erb

```
<%= link_to new_challenge_path, data: { modal: true } do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <b>Challenge</b>
<% end %>
```

A modal pops up for **`new.html.erb`**:

### new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge, html: { data: { modal: true } })  do |f| %>
 etc...
<% end %>
```

### challenges_controller

```
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new
  respond_modal_with @challenge
end

def create
  @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
  if params[:step] == '2'
    respond_modal_with @challenge
    @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
    @challenge.save
  end
end
```

And once the user clicks `f.submit` on **`new.html.erb`** he is redirected_to **`create.html.erb`** since it is `:step, 2` in the process. I want **`create.html.erb`** to also be in a modal though, which for some reason it is not.

### create.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@challenge, html: { data: { modal: true } })  do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :step, 2 %>
  etc...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way as the create action's job is to just create resources using the data that is passed into it through params.

**HTTP methods**

These are HTTP methods GET, POST, PUT, DELETE .Among this only GET has any kind of view related to it and the other types are for creating, updating and deleting resources. As create action is of type POST it must not have any view for it.More information [here](http://b-simple.de/download/restful_rails_en.pdf)

So coming to the solution your requirement is to get the data from user in steps, you can make use of this jquery [plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples) to do within the single file new.html.erb you need not have separate files for each step in form.

Comment: Thanks sghosh for your help. I went with this guy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349154/how-to-create-after-second-step-form. It works except for getting `create.html.erb` to show in a modal. Are you saying there is no way to get it to show in a modal unless I reverse course and use your suggested plugin? I know it seems hacky but he has 120K reputation whereas you have less reputation than a nun in a harim.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com my point was not that it can't be done, it was to do it the right way(following the practices and patterns) thats the reason why those have been formed and according to REST POST method aren't mean't for gettting the input from user i.e through views, and BTW almost everything is possible in programming you can even do that in a single action. At the end its your call, which way you choose to do it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks sg! I gotcha. You know how it's possible then to make the modal work with create.html.erb? Or why it isn't working?